# How can I create "profile" urls without explicit passing arguments in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am kinda new at django. For example let's say I'd like to create a BrAnD nEw social network as a pet project. I want my urls to look something like example.com/my-profile but not as example.com/profile/slug_or_pk. I have a user and profile models in different apps for now. Is it actually possible somehow to hide the slug?

Models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name='User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True)
    about = models.TextField('About', null=True, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField("Avatar", upload_to=f"profile/", blank=True, null=True)
    cover = models.ImageField("Cover", upload_to="profile/", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.user.username)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Profile"
        verbose_name_plural = "Profiles"
```

views.py

```
class ProfileDetail(DetailView):
    model = Profile
    context_object_name = 'profile'
    template_name = 'user_detail.html'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>/', ProfileDetail.as_view(), name='profile_detail'),
]
```

And the root URLconf:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('register/', RegisterUserView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('login/', LoginUserView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', LogoutUserView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('profile/', include('profiles.urls')),
    path('posts/', include('posts.urls')),
]
```

I've looked over tutorials, articles and etc.but I didn't manage to find something really useful. Maybe I am wrong somewhere at the fundamentals. Please help!

Comment: `example.com/my-profile` should work just fine.  Look up the userid of the currently logged in user, and render that user's profile.

Comment: Thank u for a reply!
Could u please explain it.. more technical?
I just can't understand how django figure it out if it is a profile we need!

I should check in view if user is logged in and get him? Sounds very closely to truth.. 
As I use generic CBV's, maybe, it'll be a good idea to create a 'get' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need is Django's `TemplateView` with `LoginRequiredMixin` (this will make sure, that `User` is authenticated):

```py
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "user_profile.html"
```

urls:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProfileView.as_view(), name='user_profile'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', ProfileDetail.as_view(), name='profile_detail'),
]
```

In the template just refer to `request.user` as the `User` model instance and you will always get data related to `User` that is actually seeing the site. In example:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            First name
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ request.user.first_name }}
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Last name
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ request.user.last_name }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: WOW! It actually was THAT easy? Actually one url is enough for that, and no DetailView needed.. Shame on me, and it's time to rest some time.. In any case, I didn't know about possibility to call request in templates for some strange reason. You are awesome, great thanks! karma++ for u ahahah